# Is it correct and natural to say "I like strategy" meaning I like strategy video games?

Tags: grammar

Could you tell me if it's correct and natural to say *I like strategy* meaning I like strategy video games? For example:

> Person A: What's your favorite genre of video games?
>
> Person B: I like **strategy**.

If it's not natural, would it be more natural to say *I like strategies* or *I like strategy games* or either one works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's your favorite **genre** of video games?

Note the emphasis.

Yes, its natural to omit redundant parts. In context, "strategy" is fully sufficient. In fact I would say that answering the question with "I like strategy (video) games" sounds stilted and unnatural. It is already established that the conversation is about video games, stating the obvious again does not convey any new information.

*I like strategies* on the other hand would likely be perceived as wrong or at least unnatural. The genre is usually given as singular, as it is the description of a class of games, not given as plural. If you want to use plural, use "strategy games".